# Proving a set is open and dense.

Tags: real-analysis

$F = [f_i ]_{i\epsilon\mathbb{N}}$. 
Let $F$ be a counting of the rational numbers. Show that 
$$\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(f_i - \frac{1}{i+1} , f_i +\frac{1}{i+1}\right)$$  is both open and dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, I've solved problems where I simply find sets that are both open and dense given some set,
but nothing like this. There also seems to be no constraint on the Lesbegue measure, though I'm not sure if that makes it easier or harder.

Comment: HINT: Your set is a union of open intervals and it contains $\mathbb{Q}$, which is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : use the density of rational numbers over real numbers ( even if what you wrote doesn't make sense) but this is a natural idea that can come to anyone's mind to show that it's open use definition